# Exception thrown while executing UI block when using react-native-svg

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-svg

My app suddenly started crashing and gave me that error:

```
Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[__NSCFNumber firstObject]: unrecognized selector 
sent to instance 0xb553069cd18775de`
```

After sometime I was able isolate the part that generates the error and found out that it has to do with the Svg component imported from react-native-svg. 
I tried removing and reinstalling node_modules and I tried reseting the cache, and I even tried creating a new expo app from scratch that does nothing but render an Svg component, but the problem still persists.

And on android I get a different error message:

```
Error while updating property 'fill' of a View managed by: RNSVGGroup
null
java.Lang.Double cannot be cast to
java.Lang.String
```

Here's what my code looks like:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Svg } from 'react-native-svg';

const App = () =>  (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Svg width={100} height={100}>

    </Svg>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
});

export default App;
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: The same situation. Reinstalling the package react-native-svg with "expo install" helped me.

Comment: That did solve it for me.. thanks @JavlonTulkinov

Comment: If you installed it using npm, remove the package first using `npm uninstall`. Then use `expo install` as @JavlonTulkinov mentioned.

Comment: For anyone encountering this problem with `react-native-svg-charts` and expo make sure to uninstall both `react-native-svg-charts` and `react-native-svg`, then first do `expo install react-native-svg`, then `npm install --save react-native-svg-charts`. Lost my entire day to this.

Comment: I have solved a simillar problem here for Victory Native: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73302893/614065

Comment: @Jesse u may have lost a day but u most certainly saved me one :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on Javlon's comment the solution is to remove the package using `npm uninstall react-native-svg` or `yarn remove react-native-svg`
 And then installing it again with `expo install react-native-svg`

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue when using `react-native-heroicons` version `3.2.0`.
https://github.com/ecklf/react-native-heroicons

I downgraded `react-native-svg` which also gets installed with `react-native-heroicons` from `13.0.0` to `12.3.0` which then started to work.

To uninstall and install 12.3.0 version of react-native-svg follow below:
`npm uninstall react-native-svg`
`npm install react-native-svg@12.3.0`